# Count unique total for combined multiple values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that records the products associated with certain accounts. I want to summarise the total number of accounts for a specific set of products, only counting each account number once, no matter how many products they have. So the total for this sample would be 4. (a + b + c + d)

| Account | Product |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 1 |
| c | 2 |
| d | 3 |

The code I have tried so far is

```
filter(Product == 1 | 2 | 3) %>%
  summarise(total = n_distinct(), .groups = Account)
```

This gives message *Error in summarise_verbose(.groups, caller_env()) :
object 'Account' not found*

I also tried

```
filter(Product == 1 | 2 | 3) %>%
  summarise(total = n_distinct(Account))
```

But this doesn't reduce the number of rows properly - I'm still getting 300,000 rows when I should get 70,000 based on other data I have. Is there a way of counting the (alphanumeric) account numbers once and once only, no matter what the products are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of an example of minimal data, I suppose you want to count the different elements by groups and using filters.

```
Data %>%
filter(Product  %in% c(1,2,3)) %>%
group_by(Account) %>%
  summarise(
    total = n_distinct(Product)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close

```
df %>%
  group_by(Account) %>%
  summarise(
    total = n_distinct(Product)
  )
```